# How can I create a Dataframe based on an unstructured CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, loops, csv

I have a very messy csv file in Python and I need to extract some relevant information from it.

Basically, there are 2-3 things that I need there: (1) two numbers separated from comma, positioned in the end of each row, (2) a 5 number code that appears in a few rows always after the letters XPTO.

The file starts with a few nonsense codes and numbers and then there are thousands of rows from which I need to get the information. It looks like this:

```
This is a messy file
Find the information below
!+
-### 111
@### 22
#@ 


########################
Main Information
########################
Date, Track, ABCD, Mailing, Type, ID, Serie
202001, AJDSOFVC, @mail.com, 2932jf, 1000, 10
202001, AJDSOFVC, @yahoo, 2932jf, 555, 22
202001, FDDDFIDi, @mail.com, 2932jf, 4000, 2
202001, code0-XPTO10010, @mail.com, 2932jf, 333, 10
202001, AJDSOFVC, @mail.com, 2932jf, 300, 10
202001, XPTO23134, @font, 2932jf, 1000, 44
202001, blabo___XPTO34111, @mail.com, 2932jf, 2555, 11
```

It's all very messy, but I know the row with the word ID appears in every file.

I need to create a new dataframe with the two last numbers in each row and the code after XPTO, if it exists. It should look like this:

```
Num_1      Num_2      Code
1000       10         Null
555        22         Null
4000       2          Null
333        10         10010
300        10         Null
1000       44         23134
2555       11         34111
```

I've tried a few things, but I'm still missing something. For instance, I could find the XPTO with find, but I'm not sure what to do with the missing ones. Also, I know str.split(',') could help me with the two numbers in each row, so maybe combine this with a for loop? Also, I don't think read_csv() will do much, right? So is there any solution to import this data?

Since not even the separator appears equally in all rows, I've thinking about creating three lists and then create a dataframe from them. But I'm not sure how can I structure this script, if I need to do a loop and how can skip the first rows. It's very confusing and I was hoping someone could throw some light on it.

UPDATE: I found that the row in which everything begins is the same, so I started by using pandas read_csv() skipping the first 13 rows. Also, I used a random symbol as separator, that worked and now I have a file without that random header. This is what I've done:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", skiprows=13, sep='PPPPP')
```

I now have the file starting from "202001, AJDSOFVC, ...". So I now need to extract the last two numbers and the code after XPTO.

Comment: So do all the CSV files follow the same sorta format of bunch of lines of random stuff, then header row, then your data? If so, my approach would be, find which line the header starts at. Then you can use pandas.read_csv(skiprows=x), to skip the first x rows

Comment: You can do usecols parameter of read_csv() to specify which columns to use

Answer (score 0):

This should work
This code works by reading the csv with csv module, then iterating through the csv by line, until the header row is found. When it's found, we store the index and then call pd.DataFrame to create the dataframe.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

data_rows = [] #Create empty list for data
index_of_headers = 0
with open("example.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader): #Iterate through each line of csv
        print 'line[{}] = {}'.format(i, line) #print line to check manually
        if(line[i] == ["Date", "Track", "ABCD", "Mailing", "Type", "ID", "Serie"]):
            index_of_headers = i #Save index of header rpw
            break

df = pd.read_csv(data_rows, columns = ['your', 'columns', 'here'], skiprows=index_of_headers, usecols=['index or', 'column names', 'that you want to use')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for the solution. Read the data first:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=11, sep=", ")
```

Next, you should get the code. I suggest doing it like this:

```
df['Code'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x['Track'][x['Track'].rfind('XPTO')+4::] if x['Track'].rfind('XPTO') > 0 else None
    , axis=1
)
```

Then rename the columns and take only the necessary ones:

```
df.rename({'Type': 'Num_1', 'ID': 'Num_2'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df[['Num_1', 'Num_2', 'Code']]
```

The DataFrame you need is ready

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', skiprows=11, sep=r"\s*,\s*", engine="python")

df = df[['Type', 'ID', 'Track']]
df['Track'] = df['Track'].str.extract(r'XPTO(\d+)')
df.columns = ['Num_1', 'Num_2', 'Code']

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Num_1  Num_2   Code
0   1000     10    NaN
1    555     22    NaN
2   4000      2    NaN
3    333     10  10010
4    300     10    NaN
5   1000     44  23134
6   2555     11  34111
```